# Using Twilio as a backend for RapidSMS

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, twilio

I would like implement a message application using RapidSMS. I installed RapidSMS on my local machine and tested the ping &pong demo. Now I want to receive and send messages from my application.

How is Twilio used in RapidSMS? I read the installation documents, but didn't get a clear idea of the implementation. Does it require a new app?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some guidance here - this is a project that integrates the two. https://rapidsms-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: i read this document but cant install in my existing rapidsms application. In which path i need to install this package? and how it can test?

Comment: are you using virtualenv ? you just need to do `pip install rapidsms-twilio` and it will install in the env path. and add  **rtwilio** in your installed applications

Answer (score 0):

First:

1) get your app hosted somewhere besides localhost
2) create a twilio account
3) create a twilio phone number

After following the directions here: https://rapidsms-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quick-start.html you will also need to add your app's URL to your twilio phone number's Webhooks. (like this example https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/automated-survey-python-django#configure-a-twilio-number)

For example, if your rapid-sms project is hosted at `foobar.herokuapp.com`, you'd set up a primary SMS webhook in Twilio for `http://foobar.herokuapp.com/backend/twilio/`.